Schedule Jupyter notebook to run while computer off and save excel file to sharepoint
I have a Jupyter notebook that pulls data for me through an API and then outputs an excel file that I then work off. I run this every day. To access the API, I have stored my credentials locally in a folder and set it as an environment variable, I have done this as I do not want my credentials to be visible on the notebook. The resulting excel file with my desired data is then saved to a SharePoint. I then use this excel file as a data source for other excel files through power query so that all I need to do is refresh the table in my working excel files.
In a perfect world I open my laptop and just refresh the table in my working excel file and I would see updated data. The API request takes about 5 minutes and is an unnecessary handbrake on the day. As such, I would like to run the Jupyter notebook at midnight while my laptop is off and have the resulting excel file saved to my desired SharePoint.
I'm open to any suggestions on how to improve this process and how I would get my notebook to run at midnight!


I would like to run the Jupyter notebook at midnight while my laptop is off and have the resulting excel file saved to my desired SharePoint

You can't run anything on a computer while it's "off". Now if the computer is not actually powered off you can use something like a crontab (or a scheduled task in Windows) to schedule your script to run at specific times/intervals
Or if you have access to cloud computing resources you can schedule a computing task to run there (lambda on AWS for example). You may have some networking and access issues to sort through there though as well
At the core of your question is "can you schedule compute tasks?" and the short answer is "yes you can." The constraints of your work situation and how much you want to invest would drive the solution here. If your computer is on the crontab seems like a straight forward thing to do here.
